# Dell Latitude E5540 becomes offline everytime it goes to sleep

Tags: sleep

My new Dell Latitude E5540 becomes automatically offline every time it goes to sleep. The connection returns only after restarting it. It is so maddening to keep restarting your new laptop about 100 times a day.
What's the problem and it's solution?

Comment: Why would you want it to be online if it is asleep? Sleeping computers cannot do anything other than wake up.

Comment: Do you mean to say that *after resuming your laptop from sleep you cannot connect to any networks*?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the power management settings, both in the regular Windows power settings control panel AND in the power settings for the wireless card. Windows is likely shutting down the network card or putting it into a lower-power mode that's less effective at maintaining a network connection.